# Django Form, save to multiple tables

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm working on an order entry system where it'll track products, recipes, and orders for customers.  I'm trying to figure out how to create a recipe_ingredient form/template that will create a product entry, a recipe entry and an associated recipe ingredient entry(s) when the user creates a new recipe.  The form should ask for the recipe name, description, along with the ingredients(products table), and percentage.

Database Design (I don't know if I got the symbols correct)
[image]

Here's my models.py for the product/recipe/recipe ingredient

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    cost_per_pound = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    cost_per_ounce = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

class Recipe_Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe_name = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    recipe_percent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, blank=True)
```

I've got a semi-working recipe ingredient form, but the user will need to create the product first and then select it when creating the recipe and recipe ingredients.

```
def recipeCreate(request):
    RecipeIngredientFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(Recipe, Recipe_Ingredient, form=RecipeIngredientForm, extra=10, fields=('ingredient', 'recipe_percent',))
    form = RecipeForm()
    formset = RecipeIngredientFormSet()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            recipe = form.save()
            formset = RecipeIngredientFormSet(request.POST, instance=recipe)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
            return redirect('/')
    context = {'form':form, 'formset':formset}
    return render(request, 'accounts/recipe_form.html', context)
```

This is what I'm trying to have displayed to the end user...
[image]
When they create a recipe, this form shows up.  They enter the name, description, ingredients and percentages.  When they click "Submit", I want the following to happen

1. the name supplied, will create a new entry in the PRODUCT table w/ a default supplier of "8" (supplier FK), everything else blank
2. create an entry in the RECIPE table with the name and description entered
3. create the entries to the RECIPE_INGREDIENTS table with the information supplied

I know that I'll need to remove the FK relationship from PRODUCT to RECIPE....I guess once I figure out how to save a form to multiple tables, I can figure out how to re-design the database.